# KafkaStream KeyValueStore with RestController initialization

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am wondering if it's possible to initialize springboot `RestController` after Kafka stream state transitioned to `RUNNING`? I noticed that `KafkaStreams.StateListener` listens in the main thread. This prevents one to use `CountDownLatch` `countDown()` in combination with `await()`. `RestController` would await in `@PostConstruct`, which would block indefinitely. I Could start KafkaStream in a separated thread, but I'm sure I am just missing something minor in the basic understanding.

This is an example what I am trying to achieve:

Kafka Pipeline

```
@Autowired
void build(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder, Aggregator<Key, Value, Value> aggregator) {
  KStream<String, String> kStream = streamsBuilder
      .stream(topic, Consumed.with(STRING_SERDE, STRING_SERDE));

  kStream
      .filter((key, value) -> filter(value))
      .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(getKey(value), value))
      .groupByKey()
      .aggregate(initializer, aggregator, Materialized.as(CDS))
      .toStream()
      .to(store);
}

@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer streamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer() {
  return sfb -> sfb.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
    log.info("Kafka streams state change from {} to {} ", oldState, newState);
    if (newState == KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING && oldState != KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING) {
      log.info("Kafka stream state ready");
      startupLatch.countDown();
    }
  });
}
```

REST Controller

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws InterruptedException {
  startupLatch.await();

  KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = checkNotNull(factory.getKafkaStreams(), "Kafka streams is null");
  this.store = kafkaStreams
      .store(StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(CDS, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be using the [KafkaStreams.state()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#state--) method within a `while`loop until it's in a RUNNING state:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

  KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = checkNotNull(factory.getKafkaStreams(), "Kafka streams is null");
  while(kafkaStreams.state() != RUNNING) {
     ..sleep for a bit
  }
 //Do other setup stuff
}
```

But I'm not sure that's totally necessary - if you went with [Interactive Queries v2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-796%3A+Interactive+Query+v2), you don't access the stores directly, rather you issue a [Query](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/query/Query.html) with a [StateQueryRequest](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/query/StateQueryRequest.html)